# Using for loop in a specific folder using dos batch script

Tags: batch-file

I would like to run executable file using the yuv files as an input in a specific folder using batch script. However, the above code that I am using run only a time and then stop. Could anyone help me?

```
>  SET /A COUNT=1
>     for /r "F:\coding\Wetlands_1920x1080p\" %%v in (*.yuv) do (
>           TAppEncoder.exe -c EBU.cfg -f 30 -i "%%v" -wdt 1920 -hgt 1080 -o %COUNT%.yuv >%COUNT%.txt
>           SET /A COUNT+=1
>           )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A COUNT=1
for /r "F:\coding\Wetlands_1920x1080p\" %%v in (*.yuv) do (
       TAppEncoder.exe -c EBU.cfg -f 30 -i "%%v" -wdt 1920 -hgt 1080 -o !COUNT!.yuv >!COUNT!.txt
  SET /A COUNT+=1
)
```

Within a `block` (a parenthesised series of statements) `%var%` refers to the value of `var` when the block was `parsed`. To access the run-time value, you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` and then use `!var!` to retrieve the required value.

See any number of SO items on the delayedexpansion problem. (it's very common...)